# Replace value in a column SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column value like below

```
"123,345","435,321","56,432",asdef,234,12-May-2017 08:00,test
"323,545","35,21","536,32",def,34,15-Apr-2017 08:00,testing
```

Am looking to generate as below

```
123345,435321,56432,asdef,234,12-May-2017 08:00,test
323545,3521,53632,def,34,15-Apr-2017 08:00,testing
```

Need to replace , with in doubleQuotes with space. AM trying to achieve in SQL server. Need guidance.

Comment: Update the question with what you have tried so far. Hint: CharIndex, Substring and replace.

Comment: am able to acheive with C# Regex, but in sql server i was stuck..as the data is 150 MB + size and C# takes forever to parse

Answer (score 0):

You can update the columns to remove the comma using replace function.

```
update *tablename* 
set column1 = replace(column1, ',' , ''),
column2 = replace(column2, ',' , ''),
column3 = replace(column3, ',' , '')
```

Comment: how do you load to table first place...it will load first column it self as 2 columns as there is comma delimiter

Comment: VARCHAR variable takes any value as long as it is inside double quotes. Just load the the value as it is and try the update statement. I tested it.